# How can I increase distribution certificate expiry time

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

My iOS app on the app store uses push notifications. Every year, when my certificate and provisioning profile expire, we need to renew both and use the same so that Push notification keep on working on live apps.

Is there any workaround to increase the expiry time period from one year. 
Also, the Apple site mentions that certificate expires in 3 years and provisioning profile in one year but in my developer account it shows that certificate expiry date also after one year. Do certificates also expire in one year?

Also, if certificate is valid and provisioning profile is expired then what would be the behaviour on live apps for push notifications?

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep Push Notifications working, you only need to renew the APN certificate in your server. No provisioning profile to renew for that. That is if you don't want to update the app building new versions.

APN certificates always expire in one year. This certificate is no the developer or release publisher certificate you use with the provisioning profiles to build de app.

And for the last question. If your certificate is valid and the provisioning profile is expired, you don't have to do anything for your living app because push notifications will work if the APN certificate is valid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!